# Removing singular points from curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Crossposted from MO, where it is downvoted:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309908/removing-singular-points-from-curves

Basically I am interested when can we find non-singular birationally
equivalent curve.

Working over the rationals.

Q1:  Let $C : f(x,y)=0$ be singular affine curve. When can we find non-singular
curve $C_2$ birationally equivalent to $C$?

Q2:  Let $C : f(x,y,z)=0$ be singular projective curve. When can we find non-singular curve $C_2$ birationally equivalent to $C$?

Partial results:

For the affine case looks like the answer is always via disequality constraints. $x \ne x0$.

Let $(x0,y0)$ be singular point on $C$. Add new variable $z$
and let $C_2 : f(x,y)=0, z(x-x0)=1$. This removes $(x0,y0)$ from the curve
and doesn't introduce new singular points. Similar trick works if the
singular locus is not zero dimensional.

The disequality constrain trick doesn't appear to work entirely for projective curves.

Since the answer to Q2 is likely negative, can we find projective $C_2$ with only one
or few singular points?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities#Resolution_of_singularities_of_curves

Comment: @AlanMuniz Many thanks!

Comment: The blow-up method is the most intuitive one.

Comment: @AlanMuniz Over finite fields there are projective curves with only one singular point and they violate the Hasse lower bound about number of points. Does the non-singular curve acquire new points over the finite field? The simplest case is the projective closure of the pointless genus zero $1=y(x^p-x)$ over $GF(p)$. For more curves like this use the affine disequality in this question.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments: Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities#Resolution_of_singularities_of_curves), every curve $C$ over a field has a resolution of singularities, that is, a smooth curve $\widetilde{C}$ along with a proper birational map $\pi:\widetilde{C}\to C$. Thus every singular curve is birational to a smooth curve.